# N registration in Europe

Tags: aircraft-registration

Do someone knows a way how to arrange an American(N) registration of aircraft located in Europe? I mean there should be an agency that you can entrust with carrying out an American registration of an aircraft that is in Europe. I am looking for this office.

Comment: It isn't difficult, but you have to meet [certain requirements](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/register_aircraft/). Namely you need to be a citizen of the united States or a US company.

Comment: @RonBeyer, surprisingly [N55XZ](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=55XZ) appears to be registered by Austrian company, not a US one. The plane is based in Czechia and I doubt it ever operates outside Europe.

Comment: @JanHudec Looking at some records for that aircraft, it seems that the N number was registered originally to an address in Houston, TX. Maybe that is how they did it...

Comment: @RonBeyer, that would mean when you buy an airplane that has valid N registration, you can keep it even if you don't otherwise satisfy the conditions...

Answer (score 1):

The FAA handles all US aircraft registration:  [FAA Aircraft Registration](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/)  Note that there are ownership requirements related to US citizenship etc.  See [FAR 47.3](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=78202a2b282637d0353bef1963d3eb97&mc=true&node=pt14.1.47&rgn=div5#se14.1.47_13)